# Tracking changes from one database table to another?

Tags: sql, database

We have a ERP database where I have read-only permissions. Let's say the Products table in my ERP database include,

```
Products
-------
Id
Name
Description
Sku
Price
```

I have another Database (say Local database) with the same structure and data. I am trying to sync both databases, so that I can track changes happens in ERP Products table. Currently I am comparing all the columns of Local Products table with the columns of ERP Products table to find what has been changed between ERP and Local (only send these changes to server). Is this is the right way or there is another better way?

Comment: I am not sure but assume SQL Replication should help you.

Comment: @Murtaza, The ERP can be Sql Server, Oracle and MySql but LocalDb databse is SqlLite.

Comment: have you tried to use insert/update/delete trigger